# How can the XOR gate make the given circuit?

Tags: logical-operators, xor

I am trying solve the following question:

> Which of the following logic circuits meets the condition described below?
>
> [Condition] A light is turned on and off by using switches A and B located at the top and bottom of the stairs. The light can be turned on and off by using one switch, regardless of the status of the other switch

[image: Switch circuilt]

Answer Options are:

- a) AND
- b) NAND
- c) NOR
- d) XOR

The given Answer from the answer sheet is: **d) XOR** (How???)

I am confused by seeing the given answer. Please help me to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XOR gate you can toggle the state of the output when toggling any one input

- If both switches are in 0 state, the output is 0 and the light is off. Now switch on one switch and the output will be 1 (1 XOR 0 = 0 XOR 1 = 1), light will be turned on
- If one switch is 0 and one is 1, i.e light is in ON state. Suppose A = 0 and B = 1 without loss of generality

  - If we switch A to 1, light will be OFF (1 XOR 1 = 0)
  - If we switch B to 0, light will also be OFF (0 XOR 0 = 0)
- If both switches is in 1 state, light is OFF. Toggling any switches will turn the light ON

Comment: thanks @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc.But the question said that, the light can be turned on and off by using one switch, regardless of the status of the other switch.That means if A=0 and B is (either 1 or  0) the light will be OFF.However if A=1 and B is (either 1 or  0) the light will be ON.But that is not happening here.

Comment: @user5005768 the light can be turned on and off by toggling only **one** switch. Regardless of the current state, just toggle any switch and the output will be toggled independent of the other switch. That's what the question said

Comment: `The light can be turned on and off by using one switch, regardless of the status of the other switch` means regardless of B you can toggle the light status with only A. Turning A into the other position will turn the light off if it's currently on and vice versa. Have you ever seen a staircase light switch?

Answer (score 2):

```
If switch B is 0:

Switch A is 0 -> Output is 0
Switch A is 1 -> Output is 1

If switch B is 1:

Switch A is 0 -> Output is 1
Switch A is 1 -> Output is 0
```

As you can see, we can control the output using only one switch, regardless of the state of the other switch.

Comment: thanks @S. Tarık Çetin.But the question said that, the light can be turned on and off by using one switch, regardless of the status of the other switch.That means if A=0 and B is (either 1 or 0) the light will be OFF.However if A=1 and B is (either 1 or 0) the light will be ON.But that is not happening here.

Comment: @user5005768 No, it doesn't mean that. It says nowhere that 0 should turn it off, and 1 should turn it on. It just requires controlling using one switch. So regardless of the state of the other switch, "changing" the state of a switch changes the output too.